# Hide horizontal scrollbar on an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, scrollbar, hide

I need to hide the horizontal scollbar on an iframe using css, jquery or js.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182707/how-to-hide-the-parent-vertical-scrollbar-after-an-iframe-is-loaded)

Comment: iframe is not on the same domain as the parent page.

Comment: overflow-y: hidden;
Not working in Google Chrome, Safari and Opera. Try it with http://jsfiddle.net/m5Btd/3/

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this with a combination of

1. CSS `overflow-y: hidden;`
2. [`scrolling="no"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-scrolling) (for HTML4)
3. <del>and [`seamless="seamless"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-seamless) (for HTML5)</del>*

<sup>* The `seamless` attribute has **[been removed](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331)** from the standard, and [no browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless) support it.</sup>

---

```css
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://bing.com" 
        class="foo" 
        scrolling="no" >
</iframe>
```

Comment: I loaded your example on Chrome 15 and still see the scrollbars.

Comment: Adding the `scrolling="no"` attribute to the iframe seems to remove scrollbars in Chrome.

Comment: @Nick It doesn't remove it on chrome at least on my computer. http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6685/chromelj.png

Comment: @l46kok your screenshot doesn't include `scrolling="no"`

Comment: Oh.. I just clicked the link in the answer and assumed that scrolling="no" was already there.. my bad for not checking

Comment: As a note: `scrolling="no"` is not supported in *HTML5* anymore. So the suggested CSS way or the attribute [`seamless`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-seamless) (if supported) are better solutions.

Comment: thanks @insertusernamehere, I've updated the answer to reflect this new tag.

Comment: Note that the **seemless attribute is currently not supported by any of the major browsers**. http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless

Comment: The seamless attribute seems to was removed on January 2016: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331#issuecomment-173923225

Comment: This doesn't work dynamically. The attributes must be there before iframe is loaded. If you dynamically set the attributes, the scrollbar won't disappear until you refresh the iframe.Any ideas?

Answer (score 27):

set `scrolling="no"` attribute in your iframe.

Comment: Although it enjoys wide support, per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the `scrolling` attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

If you are allowed to change the code of the document inside your `iframe` and that content is visible only using its parent window, simply add the following CSS in your `iframe`:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here a very simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/u5gLoav9/

This solution allow you to:

- Keep you HTML5 valid as it does not need `scrolling="no"` attribute on the `iframe` (this attribute in HTML5 has been deprecated).
- Works on the majority of browsers using CSS [overflow:hidden](http://ww.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
- No JS or jQuery necessary.

Notes:

To disallow scroll-bars horizontally, use this CSS instead:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only applicable for websites which use Bootstrap. The responsive embed feature of the Bootstrap takes care of the scrollbars.

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WsFWhL4Y84Y"></iframe>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/00qggsjj/2/

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed