# Remove scrollbar from iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

Using this code

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="height: 185px; overflow:scroll; width: 100%" src="http://www.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=439&boxtag=7868&sec=main" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" name="cboxmain" id="cboxmain" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This is how it appears (the shoutbox on homepage of http://www.talkjesus.com)

How do I remove the horizontal scrollbar and modify the css of the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-iframe which has a better answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your css:

```
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but horizontal scroll only and still shows up in Firefox. Doesn't show up in Chrome nor IE. Also, CSS for scrollbar gets applied effectively only in IE, not FF nor Chrome (latter show default looking beige color/shades).

Comment: This won't work because the overflow happens in the iframe document, which you generally won't be able to modify because of cross-domain iframe security restrictions.

Comment: This doesn't work since this won't affect the content of the iframe, just the iframe itself. The solution is scrolling="no".

Comment: This is an incorrect answer, does not remove scrollbars in google chrome, but scrolling="no" does.

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk Your answer should be the correct solution.

Comment: Best solution should not cut the content

Comment: @TheLD Thanks mate, your solution worked perfectly, Your answer should be the perfect solution

Comment: That's not a useful answer, it does not work in Chrome.

Comment: This answer should be unaccepted. This is an incorrect answer.

Comment: Still not sure why this is an accepted answer.  Does not work on older browsers and does not effect the horizontal axis

Answer (score 467):

Add `scrolling="no"` attribute to the iframe.

Comment: able to do this with css?

Comment: Yes, but then in Chrome can't use scrollIntoView.
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137214

Comment: well, this hides the content's scrollbar, and prevents scrolling the content. it doesn't prevent the iframe's scrollbar from appearing.

Comment: The scrolling attribute on the iframe is now officially obsolete. CSS should be used instead.

Comment: @MikePoole It might be officially obsolete, but it didn't help setting `overflow:hidden;`on Chrome  65.0.3325.181, but `scrolling="no"` helped.

Comment: actually, this should be the accepted answer.... as a iframe property.... it works.

Comment: This removed the scroll bar for me, but [W3C Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) now reports `The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete.`

Answer (score 57):

This works in all browsers

```
<iframe src="http://buythecity.com"  scrolling="no" style=" width: 550px; height: 500px;  overflow: hidden;" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 36):

Adding `scroll="no"` and `style="overflow:hidden"` on iframe didn't work, I had to add `style="overflow:hidden"` on body of html document loaded inside iframe.

Comment: If this helps, there is an issue in Firefox, where if you have an element CSS `transform: scale(0.7)` or such, this will create scrollbars (which will show up in your iFrame), unless you clip it with `overflow: hidden;` on an ancestor (could be a div instead of body).

Comment: That's because it's 'scrolling=no', not 'scroll=no'.

Comment: do you mean loaded inside our loaded around? What is around what?

Comment: loaded inside
<iframe src="/test.html"> where test.html has this setting.

Comment: Good solution for the case when you don't have access to the `iframe`.

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATE:**

`seamless` attribute has been removed in all major browsers

---

Just Add `scrolling="no"` and `seamless="seamless"` attributes to iframe tag. like this:-

```
 1. XHTML => scrolling="no"
 2. HTML5 => seamless="seamless"
```

Comment: The seamless attribute has been [removed from HTML](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331).

Comment: You must use css instead of seamless attribute.

Comment: @NimaRahbar The seamless attribute may be obsolete, but css does not support iframe parameters.

Answer (score 22):

Try adding `scrolling="no"` attribute like below:

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="height:380px;width:6000px;border:none;" src='https://yoururl'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 12):

If anyone here is having a problem with disabling scrollbars on the `iframe`, it could be because the iframe's content has scrollbars on elements *below* the `html` element!

Some layouts set `html` and `body` to 100% height, and use a `#wrapper` div with `overflow: auto;` (or `scroll`), thereby moving the scrolling to the `#wrapper` element.

In such a case, nothing you do will prevent the scrollbars from showing up except editing the other page's content.

Answer (score 7):

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="height:380px;width:6000px;border:none;" src='https://yoururl'></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="myInfoDiv" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height: 100%; float: left; color: #FFF; background:#ed8719; line-height:100%; font-size:100%; font-family: sans-serif>;
```

Use the above div and it will not show scroll bar in any browser.

Comment: `seamless` attribute is not valid HTML5, not supported by most browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=seamless), and most of the other styling is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

It's the last resort, but worth mentioning:

You can use the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-element on the iframe's parent to get rid of those famous 90's scroll bars.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

**Edit:** though it's [relatively supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar), `::-webkit-scrollbar` may not suit all browsers. use with caution :)

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me. You can still scroll but you don't see the ugly scrollbar. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: none;         /* Reset default border */
  height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
  width: calc(100% + 17px);
}
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Like this you make the width of the Iframe larger than it should be. 
Then you hide the horizontal scrollbar with overflow-x: hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your css to hide both scroll bar

```
iframe 
{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-Y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your css to hide just the horizontal scroll bar

```
iframe{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me.
This is what I did in JS:

Select the iframe element:

```
var iframe_name = document.getElementById("iframe_name");
```

Add the attribute to it:

```
  iframe_name.scrolling = "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iframe:

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });
const link = document.createElement("a");
const URL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.href = URL;
link.download = filename;
//download the pdf
link.click();
//open the downloaded pdf in its default viewer
window.open(URL);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using negative margin and overflow hidden to hide the scrollbar

```
<div class="scrollbar-hider" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="scrollbar-hider-margin" style="margin-right: -17px;">
            <iframe src="" 
                    style="display: block; 
                           overflow: hidden scroll; 
                           height:calc(100vh - 65px); 
                           width: 100%" 
                    frameborder="0" loading="lazy">
             </iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"

are the two attributes that are used to remove the scroll bar and the faint line that borders the iframe.

You can combine this with other size restraining attributes to embed a page into another without it looking like you did. This helps to recreate data that you would normally have to recode and take up space on your server.

Finally, including anchors such as <href will allow you to direct the iframe to a specific portion of the page. You must of coarse create a call label on that page directed to the object.

Have fun!!!! :)

Answer (score -2):

When nothing works, float:left could safe you.

iframe{float:left; clear:both;}