# Removing double scrolling in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

New timer here but I really am doing all of this by myself. So I am learning as I go. The instructions told me that in order to remove the double scroll on my iframe to put this code in.

iFrameResize();

I have this ready but now the last few steps I do not know how to do.

The instructions said I need to install an Iframe Resizer Javascript file onto my web Server, (which is a file they gave me.) But what is my web server and how do I locate it so I can put the Iframe JV file in it?

I do not know how to find my web server to begin with. I did not make this page, but I am iframing it.

Once I can find it I can save the file in the designated folder on the web server. I know this is probably a "zoolander" question. (...it's in the computer lol...) But any help is appreciated.

http://c96.6ab.myftpupload.com/ this is the page. Thanks guys!

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe

Comment: It worked to a point but it does not show the full iframe. How do I install a java file into a web server?