# Hide vertical scrollbar in iframe

Tags: html, css

I need to remove vertical scrollbar in an iframe. I have tried using `overflow: hidden;` still not working. Please help.

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqsUo.png)

Code:

```
#iphone4 {
background-image: url("ipad_new2.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 900px;
width: 750px;
margin: auto ;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}


/*Mobile iframe CSS*/
iframe {
height: 700px;
width: 525px;
position: absolute;
top: 68px;
margin: auto ;
left: 61.99px;
overflow-y: scroll;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="iphone4" >
<iframe src="index_atish.html" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you tried   ` iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}`

Comment: @G.L.P. From the OP's question: " I have tried using overflow: hidden; "

Comment: but op didnt mentioned, tried hidden for iframe.. that's why asked

Comment: There are some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe

Comment: I suggest you to see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-iframe (is the same for vertical scrollbar)

Comment: I tried ::-webkit-scrollbar {     display: none; } and its working in chrome. But in IE its not working. also iframe{ overflow:hidden; } is not.

Answer (score 11):

overflow isn't a solution for HTML5 as the only modern browser which wrongly supports this is Firefox.

A current solution would be to combine the two:

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>

iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

[check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Comment: <iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>  locks the scrollings, I want it to scroll without being scroll bar shown in IE

Comment: Here there is an example of how to scroll without show the scrollbar, maybe it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: works fine if to set 100% height, I did it by css: height: 100vh;

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll help please check below mentioned link:

```
<div id="iphone4" >
<iframe src="index_atish.html" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>

/*Mobile iframe CSS*/
iframe {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin: auto ;
left: 0;
border:none;
}
body{margin:0px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnt014a8/2/

Comment: `seamless` is not a valid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really remove vertical scrollbar if you have dynamic content in your iframe using any css property.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23020025/7699859) answer to set height dynamically at load time. If your content inside iframe is constantly changing then you have to use something like MutationObserver and the pass the resize function as an callback defined in the linked answer.

Answer (score -2):

you could try

```
iframe{scrolling="no"}
```

Comment: This should be posted as `comment`. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer :)