# hide scroll in iframe, when iframe empty in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have iframe on my popup.In IE scroll display if iframe content empty, but in other browsers it work fine. I need vertical scroll only if content is biger than iframe heigth.[image]

Comment: I think its`overflow: auto;` issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove scrollbar from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try CSS instead

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: typo: `instade` => `instead`