# How to hide scrollbar in iframe, but still be able to scroll

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have an iframe on a page with another page inside it. I want to hide the scrollbar but i can't find any solution for this.
I have tried with `overflow: hidden;` but it's not working.

See Below Code:

```
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://google.com/"></iframe>
```

CSS Code:

```
   iframe{
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: It should be possible to hide the scrollbar and still be able to scroll? @ssc-hrep3

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, that is not for an iframe window..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove scrollbar from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe)

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't work, you should add a width property to the frame same as the parent container of the frame, for my case, I want the frame to cover the whole body of my page, so I did: ``iframe{
      overflow: hidden; width:100vw !important; 
    }   `` and it got rid of the horizontal and vertical scrollbars leaving only one vertical scroll bar

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify if you need a solution for the vertical or horizontal overflow, I am assuming you are talking about the vertical one.

This can be done with the help of the parent div.

1.Set the overflow of the parent div as hidden.
2. Set the overflow of the child div to auto and the width 200% (or anything more than 100%, or more than the width of the parent - so that the scrollbar gets hidden).

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alien_no155/0gotmq3x/)

Comment: Yes but also you hide the content.

Comment: This solution does not hide the scrollbar for me...

Comment: man, that didn't work for me

Comment: the question has to do with iframe and in jsfiddle I don't see iframe, just for that I will give -1

Answer (score 0):

some parent with scrolling and hidden overflow-x with iframe 105% width
will literally hide only the scrollbar on the right

some of my snippet of my works :

```css
.narrow{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.scrollbox {
/* It is not really important but incase u are wondering*/
    color: white;
    background: var(--bgt2);
    /* padding: 25px 0px 4rem; */
    width: 470px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
} 

.scrolly-container{
/* i dont really write all the css but i just need these to set the width into 100%*/
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox scrolly-container">
            <div class="narrow" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
                    <div style="height: 100vh;">
                    <iframe id="formcontainer" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gr7gA9EpDLmSuRNvAG3aDwujG29-kNUa4a5-TNLusFM?>/viewform?embedded=true" width="120%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" >Memuat…</iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Note: it only hide scrollbar in chrome for the other i dunno

Answer (score -2):

not sure if this possible with css for iframe only, but you can use scrolling='no'

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://google.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Setting scrolling="no" prevents scrolling

Answer (score -3):

For Webkit only, try adding:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```