# Overflow hidden doesn't hide scrollbar for iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to hide the scrollbar on an iframe while retaining the scrolling functionality within an iframe. I've tried using `overflow:hidden` styling on the parent `div` and the container`, inline and from a stylesheet (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735729/2750877) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/2750877)) but to no effect, as the scrollbar remains and provides a horrible user experience as the page then will have two scrollbars. I have tested using both Chrome and Firefox, but the issue is present in both browsers.

This is what I have:

```css
.iframeParent {
  height: 4500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframeParent">
  <iframe class="iframeTag" src="www.example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

And `scrolling=no` is not an option as I still want to be able to scroll within the iframe.

Is it even possible to achieve this using only css or do I have to turn to javascript?

Comment: Do you want to hide the scrollbar on just the parent of the iframe or do you want to hide the scrollbar on the iframe itself?

Comment: Did you try `<iframe ... scrolling="no">` …?

Comment: can you make a [mcve] of this double scrollbar effect

Comment: @misorude that's not an option as I want to be able to scroll within the iframe

Comment: @NickParsons on the iframe itself

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want: visually hiding the scrollbar but scrolling functionality is retained

```css
.iframeParent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.iframeParent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.iframeParent iframe {
  width: 650px;
  height: 294px;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframeParent">
  <iframe class="iframeTag" src="www.example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```