# How do I remove a scrollbar from an iFrame?

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="{{ $graphUrl }}" width="100%" height="451px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It renders as:

[image]

I've tried

```
iframe{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

> scrolling="no"
>   seamless="seamless"
>   overflow-y: hidden;
>   overflow: hidden;

I've tried everything from the question below:

[Remove scrollbar from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe)

None of those work! Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure it's an `iframe` scroll? May be some div inside?

Comment: How do I check to make sure ?

Comment: Use browser's developer tools - inspect an element, try to change element style on the fly. Try to render `iframe` with just some very long div first. may be. You can also post some online example, so we can take a look.

Comment: We need to see a [mre]; please update your HTML to include at least an applicable sample source URL if you can't include the *actual* URL.

Comment: In the time it took you to write that comment you could have easily filled in the the src attribute 5 times.

Comment: @kyo what browser are you using? No scrollbar in Chrome on Win10.