# Embedding MS Form iframe scrolling="no" does not work

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll, ms-forms

I am trying to embedthis MS Form into SquareSpace but I get 2 scroll bars in the page (one for browser and one for this form).

```html
<iframe width="460px" height= "1000px" scrolling="no" 
src= "https:...&embed=true" 
frameborder= "0" marginwidth= "0" marginheight= "0" style= "overflow:hidden; border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" 
allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the scrollbar for the form and have only the browser scoller? Obviously the page gets a longer scroll depending on size of the form in each step

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yup, add this attribute to your iframe:

```
scrolling="no"
```

example:

```
<iframe src="http://iFrameSource.com"  scrolling="no" style="width: 550px; height: 500px;  overflow: hidden;" ></iframe>
```

Source: [Remove scrollbar from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that too! Doesn't work! Not sure why. I noticed the code doesn't show. Here is my code:

Comment: <iframe width="460px" height= "1000px" scrolling="no" 
src= "https:...&embed=true" 
frameborder= "0" marginwidth= "0" marginheight= "0" style= "overflow:hidden; border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" 
allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen> </iframe>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding following CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {margin:0; overflow: hidden;}
  iframe {border: none;}
</style>
<body> 
  <iframe height="100%" width="100%" 
   src="yourframe1.html"></iframe>
  <iframe src="yourframe2.html" 
   width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```