# iframe inner scrollbar is stuck

Tags: html, css, iframe, tailwind-css

I have a page that has an iframe in it. for styling, I'm using tailwind-css. Now I have two scrollbars - iframe inner scroll and browser'scroll, I want to hide the inner scrollbar of the iframe and scroll with the browser scrollbar. I tried to use `scrolling="no"` and the inner scrollbar is removed but the browser scroll is stuck and the iframe is not fully displayed

```
<div className="h-full overflow-scroll>
   <iframe
      src={url}
      frameBorder="0"
      width="100%"
      scrollbar="no">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove scrollbar from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082155/remove-scrollbar-from-iframe)

Comment: @Thomas I think no, my issue is that after removing inner scrollbar of iframe, browser scrollbar is stuck and doesnot scroll full iframe display

Comment: dude, if you disable the scroll bar in the iframe, you wont be able to scroll in the iframe

Comment: you need to set a height value if you want to do what you want to do

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I don't want to scroll in the iframe, I want to scroll page where I use iframe

Answer (score 0):

set the height to fit the content and disable the scrollbar

```html
<div className="h-full overflow-scroll>
   <iframe
      src={url}
      frameBorder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="640px"
      scrollbar="no">
   </iframe>
</div>
```