# How to add "scrolling=no" in an iframe using jquery/mootools?

Tags: jquery, iframe, mootools, modal-dialog

I have a link

```
<a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 500, y: 400}}" href="http://localhost/site/index.php">Site</a>
```

Which opens its href in lightbox. I want to remove scrolls from an iframe and I found this ['"scorlling=no"'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856854/902161).I could not find a  way to add this property in iframe.
I tried this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".modal").click(function() {
      $("#sbox-content iframe").attr("scrolling","no")
    });
});
```

But it's not working.
Is this possible or what is the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `overflow: hidden` for the `iframe` works. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/6RGxh/

---

Specify `overflow: hidden` for the `<html>` element in your `localhost/site/index.php` file.

Comment: Thanks this is working.But one thing I wanted to know can we do something from our side without adding anything in localhost/site/index.php

Comment: This does not work in chrome.http://stackoverflow.com/a/9678294/902161 I think for doing so we'll have to add this to localhost/site/index.php because this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
   <a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 500, y: 400},scrolling:no}" href="http://localhost/site/index.php">Site</a>
```

not sure but you may give it a shot.

Comment: Tried the same as you suggested but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `site/index.php` instead `http://localhost/site/index.php`, iframes are protected in browsers - especially when they are showing page from other domain.

Comment: Pages do open but the scroll is there.I dont want vertical scroll.