# Remove vertical scrollbar in iframe (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, css, iframe

I would like to remove (i.e. hide) the vertical scrollbar from an iframe. I have tried using `overflow:hidden` and `scroll="no"` but the scrollbar still appears.

This is what I have tried:

```
<iframe name = "iframemc" id="iframemc" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="background-color: white; float:none; margin-left:40px; overflow:hidden" runat="server" width="800px" height="620px" ></iframe>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: native html width/height attributes do not require a px value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden;` instead, `auto` I think is what adds the scrollbar:

```
<iframe name = "iframemc" id="iframemc" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="background-color: white; float:none; margin-left:40px; overflow:hidden" runat="server" width="800px" height="620px" ></iframe>
```

keep `scrolling="no"` for older browsers.

Comment: sorry my mistake, it is just a typo. I have actually used `overflow:hidden`. Still doesn't work..

Comment: You might want to edit the question - It should hide though.... Do other values like `visible` & `auto` work then?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want overflow-y: hidden

Excerpt from another answer:

> I'd suggest doing this with CSS. and overflow-y: hidden;
>
> .restricted{width:200px; height:200px; overflow-y: hidden;}

Reference:
[Hide horizontal scrollbar on an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-vertical-scrollbar-on-an-iframe)

Comment: I don't have this option in ASP.NET.. I only have the option `overflow` in `style`

Comment: Can't you use it inside a `<style>` tag? (No clue about ASP.NET...)

Comment: If you want to do this in the code behind then I would advise creating a CSS class on the page and assigning that class to the iframe using the WebControl.CssClass property  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that's what I am saying.. in the style tag, there is no option for overflow-y, there is only `overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

This example has no scrollbars in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/Asb8v/3/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" scrolling="no" name="iframemc" id="iframemc" frameborder="0" runat="server" ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #iframemc {
        background-color: white; 
        float:none; 
        margin-left:40px; 
        overflow:hidden
    }
</style>
```

Comment: We use Internet Explorer internally, and unfortunately, the scrollbar still shows in IE

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you see scrollbars of iframe content, not iframe itself. To get rid of scrollbars apply `overflow:hidden` and `height/width:100%` to html, body of iframe (or to element that has `overflow:auto` in iframe content). But to do so, you should have access to iframe content.