# How to disable the scroll bar for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to disable the scroll bar in iframe and yet load the complete web page and scroll up and down with browser scroll bar?  The iframe should look as its a part of the page and not iframe.

Comment: using scrolling=no or set overflow:hidden for iframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-vertical-scrollbar-on-an-iframe

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML iframe - disable scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
```

When present, [seamless](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp) attribute specifies that the `<iframe>` should look like it is a part of the containing document and then no borders or scrollbars. Bad point is only supported in Opera, Chrome and Safari.

and with css:

```
iframe { 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: As a note: `scrolling="no"` is not supported in *HTML5* anymore. So the CSS way or the attribute [`seamless`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-seamless) (if supported) are better solutions.

Comment: Good point. I add into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

or

```
 iframe { 
    overflow:hidden; 
 }
```

or

```
 iframe {
      overflow-x:hidden;
      overflow-y:hidden;
  }
```

Comment: @VineetGNair don't say thanks.