# Valid HTML5 iframe code shows scrolling bar on IE8

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've replaced the iframe code:

```
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
```

with

```
style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border:0px; margin:0px"
```

It works well on all browsers except IE8 which displays ugly scrolling bars.

Is there any way to remove them ?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle with your iframe as well as css

Comment: Please see live website: http://informacje.gwiazdytv.pl/ (refresh a few times under IE8 and you will see that ads are displayed with scroll bars).

Comment: ITS IE 8! NOTHING EVER LOOKS GOOD! BLOCK IE 8 AND MOVE ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856854/4952851 although ignore the `overflow-y` as you already have the general `overflow` catering for x and y. Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Failing that just make the iframe a little bigger (if it won't be a problem with the page layout) to cater for the slightly larger ads as Olli has suggested. I ALWAYS have to make iframes a little larger than they're supposed to be in order to display correctly.

Incidentally, it isn't specific to IE8, it happens in IE11 also (I haven't checked any others but I'm using IE11 and it has the same problem). Here's a capture from IE11:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few things that you can do, Currently the iframe has a size of 750 x 200px.
If you make the frame a bit larger (~20px) the scrollbars most likely will dissappear.

You might want to try to add the following code examples directly to the frame.

```
scroll="no" style="overflow:hidden"
```

or this code

```
scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"
```