# -ms-overflow-style: none Doesn't work with IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

I need to hide the scrollbar which is found in iframe when using IE 11.

As I read "-ms-overflow-style: none" works with IE 10 and can do what I need:

[Unlike overflow: hidden, elements with -ms-overflow-style: none can still be scrolled via touch panning, keyboard, or mouse wheel.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx)

Any suggestion please?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd take a look at this, adding scrolling="no" and seamless="seamless" to the iframe should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-iframe

Comment: Thank you. But scrolling="no" remove the scrolling and I need to have it without scrollbar. About seemless, i can't use it because the iframe created by jQuery under the control of Prestashop.