# How to delete scrollbars on an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I added a basic iframe to my website, and it is showing scrollbars (vertical and horizontal) that I can't get rid of in any way. I've been reading a lot about it on the Net, and nothing seem to work (like overflow: hidden, or scrolling="no"). What is the best and most standard way of fixing this, as of now / 2016?

Thanks!

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856746/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-iframe

Comment: I added the code from @Jasper van Merle answer and also added overflow: hidden to body within the iframe, an it works.

Comment: Nice ... You are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS:

```
iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This works in Chrome, which is good, but it does not work in Explorer and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

i would say 
`<iframe scrolling="no" src="..." >`
CSS

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="ifrm">
        <iframe src="http://tholman.com/elevator.js/" height="300" width="300" scrolling="no"</iframe>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<iframe>` scrolling attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. The scrolling attribute specifies whether or not to display scrollbars in an `<iframe>`. Normally, scrollbars appear in an `<iframe>` when the content is larger than the `<iframe>`.

```
iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```